# C# How to send a rendered HTML page to the printer

Tags: c#, html, printing

from a CLI application (or library) in C#, i can send something to the printer, select it etc (using  `PrintDocument` and `PrinterSettings`.

How can I send to a printer a rendered HTML page? Like instantiating in memory IE and use it to render / print the page? This without opening an actual browser window (ex, do it all from the command line).

This is where I've got so far:

```
    using mshtml;

    string sWebPage = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\me\Desktop\h.html");
    object[] oPageText = { sWebPage };
    HTMLDocumentClass myDoc = new HTMLDocumentClass();
    IHTMLDocument2 oMyDoc = (IHTMLDocument2)myDoc;
    oMyDoc.write(oPageText);
    //oMyDoc.execCommand("print", false, 0); <- does not wok
```

Thanks

Comment: it's a little unclear what exactly you're asking - do you want to print a web page from a web app, or render and print some HTML from a non-web app?

Comment: load a html string and format it as proper html in memory. from there send the rendered page to a printer of choice.

Answer (score 1):

You could use Internet Explorer via COM and set the visibility of the browser to false.
Let me know if you need an actual code example.

```
using SHDocVw;
        InternetExplorer ie = new InternetExplorer();            
        ie.Visible = false;
        ie.Navigate("http://xxx");
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        while (ie.Busy)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
```

,,,
...

Answer (score 1):

There's a [WebBrowser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.aspx) control that looks like it lets you load and render some HTML, and does have a Print method, but it's a form control so it may be tough to use in a non-Forms project.

Answer (score -1):

Using `Javascript`, `window.print()` will send the HTML page to the printer. Check out [W3Schools reference](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_print.asp)

Comment: That false, it will open the Print Select page.